Exact time point of assignment
Consider this plain TeX code:
\the\dimen0

\dimen0=1pt\the\dimen0\the\dimen0
\bye

which produces

0.0pt
0.0pt.0pt

Here is my analysis: the first line is obvious, and it shows that the original value in \dimen0 is 0pt. For the third line, since there is no space character after 1pt, TeX needs to look forward to find the "complete" <dimen> representation for the dimen variable assignment. So at the point right after 1pt, \the\dimen0 is still 0pt.
But note that there is also no space character after the second \the\dimen0, so TeX needs to look forward to find the complete <number> of the \dimen register. Thus TeX expands the last \the\dimen0 to 0.0pt. After this, the third line becomes
\dimen0=1pt\the\dimen00.0pt

Then \the\dimen00 expands to 0.0pt and the third line becomes
\dimen0=1pt0.0pt.0pt

TeX can only recognize 1pt in 1pt0.0pt.0pt as a legitimate dimen, so it sends 0.0pt.0pt to the output stream and then do the assignment for \dimen0. Is my analysis correct?

Up to the last line you were correct.
The assignment then happens while 0.0pt.0pt is still in the input buffer, then after the assignment happens the first 0 will trigger a new paragraph, indentation will be added then the following tokens will be set as text.

Thank you for your quick response as always :-)@DavidCarlisle

Almost correct. I'll add some more details.
For uniformity, TeX tries to expands any token following a keyword, and units of measure (among which pt, cm, mm and so on) are keywords. A single space token will be ignored.
\edef\twospaces{\space\space}

x\dimen0=1pt\space\space x

x\dimen0=1pt\twospaces x

x\space\space x

\bye

More spaces may be ignored if the argument after the keyword can be preceded by a <filler> such as to
\edef\twospaces{\space\space}

x\hbox to \twospaces 10pt{x\hss}x

x\hskip 10pt x

\bye

Your analysis is good up to a point. The assignment \dimen0=1pt is only finalized when the optional space after the keyword has been discarded or the first following token has been examined and isn't a space.
The process applies notwithstanding that nothing after pt can influence the assignment (it would be very different if \dimen were \skip, look for “Quick, Jonathan Oratio” in the index).
The process is similar when numbers are being determined. The \dimen token after \the needs to find an integer and so TeX will expand tokens after 0 until finding something that's not a digit and discarding the optional space. So the second \the is expanded.
At this point, the first \the hasn't been expanded yet, so TeX has
\dimen0=1pt\the\dimen00.0pt

Now \the knows what to apply to, which is \dimen00 that's the same as \dimen0. Next the input stream will have
\dimen0=1pt0pt.0pt

Now the assignment is performed and the 0 following pt triggers starting a paragraph.
